Async iterators zip in python
I have two iterators:
async def iter1():
   for i in range(5):
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       yield 1

async def iter2():
       for i in range(10):
       await asyncio.sleep(1)
       yield 2

I want to create a function async_zip_stream(*args, default_value=0).
It should iterate over all the passed iterators simultaneously without synchronization, yielding tuples of values. If any iterator doesn't generate a value at some point, it should return the default_value.
So in this case, the output would be:
1, 0
1, 0
1, 0 
1, 0
1, 0 
0, 2
....

I don't quite understand how this can be done without synchronization between the iterators.

So you want to synchronise the output of your async functions without any synchronisation?

The chances of both events happening at the same time are as close to zero as you can get, so you'll never see both values in your tuple.

async def async_zip_stream(*iterators, default_value=0):
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(iterator.__anext__()) for iterator in iterators]
    done = [False] * len(iterators)
    
    while not all(done):
        results = []
        
        for i, task in enumerate(tasks):
            if done[i]:
                results.append(default_value)
            elif task.done():
                try:
                    results.append(task.result())
                    tasks[i] = asyncio.create_task(iterators[i].__anext__())
                except StopAsyncIteration:
                    done[i] = True
                    results.append(default_value)
            else:
                results.append(default_value)
        
        yield tuple(results)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)  # Slight delay to allow other tasks to progress


